# RewriteCond & RewriteRule ignore folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an URI `domain.tld/a/b/c.php?p=123` that I want to redirect to another one (`otherdomain.tld`) while ignoring all foldernames and parameters.

This is what I have added to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.tld$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a/b/c.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://otherdomain.tld/?
```

The result is nice and the redirect to otherdomain.tld happens as intended, parameters are removed and everything, but I end up at this URI:

```
otherdomain.tld/b/
```

I do not understand why folder "b" is still there. Could someone please explain it to me and point me to where my error in my RewriteRule (or RewriteCond) is? Thank you.

### Solution

I found the solution myself through a hint by @starkeen. Since there were other RewriteRules with other RewriteConditions, I have have added two flags - R and L - and it worked like charm. So the last rule now reads like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://otherdomain.tld/? [R,L]
```

...and everything works fine.

Comment: Do you have any other rewrite rules?

Comment: @starkeen, yes there were other rewrite rules and this made me rethink the whole thing. I added `[R,L]` to the RewriteRule and this solved my problem.